# Hyperledger Fabric: what happens to the existing transactions when a chaincode is upgraded?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Comparing to Ethereum, if a Smart Contact is upgraded, it will create a new address and we can't access to the existing data of the old Smart Contact. To handle this, we need to implement the design pattern of solidity.

I like to know how this works when upgrading a chaincode is done in Hyperledger Fabric. Is it possible to access the data in the old chaincode after upgrading the chaincode?

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it is possible to access the data in the old chaincode after ugrading the chaincode.

Data is kept into ledger hosted by peer StateDB or CouchDB and chaincode is the business logic to read, write & update data.

You will upgarde your chaincode, but the key-value pair, that stored on peer database(StateDB or CouchDb) will not change.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, it should be noted that you can deploy Smart Contracts at Ethereum that later you can upgrade, preserving their address, state, and balance.

Responding to your question: it doesn't happen anything to the existing transaction, because they have been stored at the previous blocks of the Blockchain. So, the data stored at that transactions will be available for you. The data is stored at the blocks of the chain, the Smart Contract manages whick operations could be executed.

At Hyperledger Fabric the performance of the Smart Contracts is similar to Ethereum. You define the methods and params that you could execute. While you use this chaincode, your data will be storing at the Blockchain following the definition of your chaincode. Once you upgrade it, you will access to the data if the new chaincode allows it. Regardless of it, the data will be at the chain of blocks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. practically, as I know we always get a new address after installing a new smartcontract. if we compare to relational db in which we can modify the column and data after deployment. how can we do this with hyperledger fabric? Regrading to your answer, how can we implement the new chaincode to access the data of the previous verison?

Comment: If you upgrade a chaincode, you will continue accessing to the data of the previous chaincode. It is done automatically by Hyperledger Fabric.